# Finding Duplicates & Renaming Master/Child

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that is finding duplicates and highlighting the cell:

```
Private Sub cmdDups_Click()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range(Range("C1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In Rng
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

However, it is confusing because it just highlights them all. How would I go about adding a subfix on to them such as MASTER and CHILD. Master based on when the first one found, and child for anything after.

Is that possible?

Comment: Very easy using just formulas on Excel, you sure you need VBA?

Comment: Hi, yes unfortunately VBA :(

Comment: You cannot add a suffix, that would change the items during your loop and make duplicates unique. So it is only possible to store the master/child information in another column.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, it's quite possible though, using a simple array? Or am I thinking too simplistic here?

Comment: @JvdV Right, I was not precise ^^: You cannot add a suffix to the same data you are looping through, as this would change duplicates to uniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would refrain from calling the sheet too often. It usually is prefered to work through memory. The following might look quite extensive but I tried to write some comments to make it clear:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, arr As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

    'Find last used row in column C and prepare array to read through memory
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("C1:C" & lr)
    arr = rng1.Value

    'Loop over array and create a range object through Union and check against dictionary
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, arr(x, 1)) > 1 Then
            If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng2 = Union(rng2, .Cells(x, 3))
            Else
                Set rng2 = .Cells(x, 3)
            End If
            If dict.exists(arr(x, 1)) Then
                arr(x, 1) = "CHILD " & arr(x, 1)
            Else
                dict(arr(x, 1)) = 1
                arr(x, 1) = "MASTER " & arr(x, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Read back array and change cells colors
    rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    rng1.Value = arr

End With

End Sub
```

Before:

[image: ![enter image description here]

After:

[image]

Comment: And I'm thinking it could be worth testing to add all values and their count into another dictionary for comparison. I haven't tested on large datasets but might be worth it over worksheetfunction.countif =)

Comment: That is very clever, something I would have not come up with on my own - thanks for taking the time

Comment: @BCLtd, these are fun little things to work on. My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rngWhole As Range, rngSplit As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngWhole = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngWhole, .Range("A" & i).Value) > 1 Then

                Set rngSplit = .Range("A1:A" & i)

                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSplit, .Range("A" & i).Value) = 1 Then
                    .Range("B" & i).Value = "MASTER"
                Else
                    .Range("B" & i).Value = "CHILD"
                End If

                .Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Note:**

This is not the fastest solution.